# Tools for globally installing Firefox extensions?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, firefox-profile

I use multiple Firefox profiles (in a single machine).  Occasionally I come across a FF extension that I would like to make available over all these profiles.  I understand that the way to do this is to run:

```
/path/to/firefox -install-global-extension /path/to/extension.xpi
```

I have several related questions.  First

> Is there a FF extension that provides an interface to this command that is as convenient as the "standard" interface.

(By "standard interface" above I mean a button or hyperlink that, when clicked, causes the download and installation of some extension *for the current profile only*.  I'm looking for the same convenience for installing extensions globally.)

If my Google results are to be trusted, I imagine that the answer to the question above is no.  In this case, my second question is:

> Is there a way to streamline the process of *downloading* (without installing) an extension's *.xpi file?

Again, here I just want to have something as convenient as the "standard interface".  In this case it would be to replace the "install" behavior or the "standard interface" with a "download only" behavior.

(I would then use a home-grown script to run the command mentioned above on each of these downloads.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to download extensions would be to use a browser that does not support xpi files. Since it does not know what to do it will prompt to download them.